# Matlab kmeans clustering for non linearly separable data

Tags: matlab, k-means

I've a non linearly separable data at my hand. I want to cluster it using K-means implementation in matlab. I want to get the cluster labels for each and every data point, to use them for another classification problem.

The problem is k-means is not giving results as expected. I'm attaching the cluster plot I obtained.

I expected k-means to give clusters as concentric circles as the data looks, but output was arcs. I don't understand why is this happening.

Can you suggest me any other clustering method to acheive my goal. 
[image: My cluster plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before using an algorithm, you should try to *understand* it: what is the goal of an algorithm, and how does it achieve it. For k-means, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) tells us the following:

> k-means clustering aims to partition n observations into k clusters in which each observation belongs to the cluster with the nearest mean

Three concentric circles would have the exact same mean, so k-means is not suitable to separate them. The result is really what you should expect from k-means here.

Now, if you know that your clusters will *always* be concentric circles, you can simply convert your cartesian (x-y) coordinates to polar coordinates, and use only the radius `rho` for clustering - as you know that the angle `theta` doesn't matter:

```
% Create random data
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(2*pi*rand(1000,1),rand(1000,1));
[x2,y2] = pol2cart(2*pi*rand(1000,1),rand(1000,1)+2);
[x3,y3] = pol2cart(2*pi*rand(1000,1),rand(1000,1)+4);
X = [x1,y1; x2,y2; x3,y3];

% Transform to polar
[theta,rho] = cart2pol(X(:,1),X(:,2));

% k-means clustering
idx = kmeans(rho,3);

% Plot results
hold on
plot(X(idx==1,1), X(idx==1,2), 'r.')
plot(X(idx==2,1), X(idx==2,2), 'g.')
plot(X(idx==3,1), X(idx==3,2), 'b.')
```

[image: result]

Or more generally: use a suitable kernel for k-means clustering, or use another algorithm.